# SKLearn Decision Tree Classifier Depth/Order

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

While reviewing the decision tree documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html), I noticed the classifier does not have a means to adjust the "order" of the fit. Specifically, regarding the call:

```
tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
```

I would like to play around with high / low "orders" to see how the decision surface visual changes.

The call to the *Regressor* does seem to have this feature:

```
regr_1 = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=2)
regr_2 = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=5)
```

Does the `DecisionTreeClassifier()` call not have comparable arguments? I would presume in some instances it would be vital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DecisionTreeClassifier has a `max_depth` argument, too. See [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html).

```
>>> from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
>>> from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
>>> clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2)
>>> iris = load_iris()
>>> cross_val_score(clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=10)
```